# Strange UIKit bug, table view row stays selected

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview

I'm facing what appears to be a UIKit bug, and it takes the combination of two less commonly used features to reproduce it, so please bear with me here.

I have quite the common view hierarchy:

```
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UITableViewController
```

and the table view controller pushes another table view controller onto the navigation controller's stack when a row is selected. There's absolutely nothing special or fancy in the code here.

However, the second `UITableViewController`, the "detail view controller" if you will, does two things:

1. It sets `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` in its `init` method, so the tab bar is hidden when this controller is pushed:

   ```
   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
       if(self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
           self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
       }
       return self;
    }
   ```
2. It calls `setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES` and `setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES` on `self.navigationController` in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` respectively, causing the `UIToolbar` provided by `UINavigationController` to be displayed and hidden with animations:

   ```
   - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
   }

   - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
       [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
   }
   ```

Now, if the second `UITableViewController` was pushed by selecting the row at the bottom of the screen (it doesn't have to be the last row) in the first controller, this row does not automatically get deselected when the user immediately or eventually returns to the first controller.

Further, the row cannot be deselected by calling `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` on `self.tableView` in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` in the first controller.

I'm guessing this is a bug in `UITableViewController`'s drawing code which of course only draws visible rows, but unfortunately fails to determine correctly if the bottommost row will be visible in this case.

I failed to find anything on this on Google or OpenRadar, and was wondering if anyone else on SO had this problem or knew a solution/workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem, (though I am not using a toolbar).  My solution was to deselect the row in didSelectRowAtIndexPath after pushing my second view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RunViewController *runViewController = [[RunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RunViewController" bundle:nil];
    runViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    runViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:runViewController animated:YES];
    [runViewController release];

     //deslect "stuck" row
    [aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Of course this is different from the default and expected behavior.

Comment: Well, when it started happening, I certainly thought that it was unexpected, but the solution above worked for me so I didn't really pursue it any further.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well I think I had same/similar problem once, but my solution was rather rough:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // ...
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```